# How to control loading flag with react-redux in same component?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I create a project with `react-redux`, my project has a lots of cities, click each on of cities will navigate to my class component `TheaterList.js`

I set my reducer has a `loading` flag (the default is `true` when fetch data succeed then return it with `false`)with my action `MOVIELIST_THEATER`, here is my `MovieListReducer.js` code:

```
import { 
  MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY, 
  MOVIELIST_THISWEEK,
  MOVIELIST_THEATER,
  MOVIELIST_TIME,
  MOVIE_DETAIL
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  mainMovie: [],
  thisWeek: [],
  theaterList: [],
  timeList: [],
  movieDetail: [],
  loading: true
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        mainMovie: action.payload
      };
    case MOVIELIST_THISWEEK:
      return {
         ...state,
         thisWeek: action.payload
      };
    case MOVIELIST_THEATER:
      return {
         ...state,
         theaterList: action.payload,
         loading: false 
      };
    case MOVIELIST_TIME:
      return {
        ...state,
        timeList: action.payload
      };
    case MOVIE_DETAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        movieDetail: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And here is my class component `TheaterList.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTheater } from '../actions';
import { Spinner } from './common';

class TheaterList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    const { enCity } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    this.state = { 
      navigation: this.props.navigation,
      enCity
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchTheater({ enCity: this.state.enCity });
  }

  renderItem({ item }) {
    // some view tag
  }

  render() {
    const theaters = this.props.theaterList;
    // the default is true when fetch data succeed then return it with false
    if (this.props.loading) {
      return (
        <Spinner text='Loading...' />
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={theaters}
          renderItem={this.renderItem} 
          numColumns={1}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const theaterList = state.listType.theaterList;
  const loading = state.listType.loading;

  return { theaterList, loading };
};

const styles = {
 // some style settings
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchTheater })(TheaterList);
```

It works very well at first , like shows the `<Spinner />` wait until the data return and re-render state then show my `<FlatList />`, but when i go back to screen and navigate to `TheaterList.js` again, i find `this.props.loading` value is still `false`. It causes my `<Spinner />` will not show out.

I try to control the loading flag, add `this.props.loading = true;` under `componentDidMount()` function. Obviously it is not right.

Here is my `action.js`:

```
import { 
  MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY, 
  MOVIELIST_THISWEEK,
  MOVIELIST_THEATER,
  MOVIELIST_TIME,
  MOVIE_DETAIL 
} from './types';

export const fetchMainMovieList = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch('https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=Taipei&theater=Centuryasia')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        dispatch({ type: MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY, payload: responseData[0].movie });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
};

export const fetchThisWeek = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch('https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/thisWeek')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        dispatch({ type: MOVIELIST_THISWEEK, payload: responseData[0].movie });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));    
  };
};

export const fetchTheater = ({ enCity }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/drivers?city=${enCity}&lng=121.584065&lat=25.041317`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        console.log(responseData);
        dispatch({ type: MOVIELIST_THEATER, payload: responseData });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));    
  };
};

export const fetchTime = ({ enCity, theater }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=${enCity}&theater=${theater}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        dispatch({ type: MOVIELIST_TIME, payload: responseData[0].movie });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));    
  };
};

export const fetchDetail = ({ enCity, cnName }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/detail?city=${enCity}&movie=${cnName}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        dispatch({ type: MOVIE_DETAIL, payload: responseData[0].movie });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));    
  };
};
```

So how exactly set the `loading` flag with `react-redux` if use the same class component ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

According to @MRFrhn advice i make some change.

In my `action.js` add `dispatch({ type: MOVIE_REQUEST_THEATER });` before fetch the data:

```
export const fetchDetail = ({ enCity, cnName }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: MOVIE_REQUEST_THEATER });

    fetch(`https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/detail?city=${enCity}&movie=${cnName}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        dispatch({ type: MOVIE_DETAIL, payload: responseData[0].movie });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));    
  };
};
```

In my reducer add a case:

```
case MOVIE_REQUEST_THEATER:
  console.log('MOVIE_REQUEST_THEATER');
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: true, // show the spinner
  };
```

I think it should succeed, because i return `loading` flag `true` before fetch the data , but it is no working then i see my log, `console.log('MOVIE_REQUEST_THEATER');` doesn't show out.  Don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first time fetch your data, `loading` is true (from initial state) and when you get the response, you set it to **false**, but you never set it to true again, so it will be false the next time you read it. You must set it to **true** each time you want to fetch. You may also need to handle errors, like when your request fails, so for the right way to implement this in redux, you need 3 actions for your request:

1. **An action informing the reducers that the request began.** The reducers may handle this action by toggling an `isFetching` flag (or `loading` in your code) in the state. This way the UI knows it's time to show a spinner. e.g. action type `MOVIELIST_THEATER_REQUEST`
2. **An action informing the reducers that the request finished successfully.** The reducers may handle this action by merging the new data into the state they manage and resetting `isFetching`. The UI would hide the spinner, and display the fetched data. e.g. action type `MOVIELIST_THEATER_SUCCESS`
3. **An action informing the reducers that the request failed.** The reducers may handle this action by resetting `isFetching`. Additionally, some reducers may want to store the error message so the UI can display it. e.g. action type `MOVIELIST_THEATER_FAILURE`

So your reducer would look something like this:

```
case MOVIELIST_THEATER_REQUEST:
  return {
     ...state,
     loading: true, // this will show the spinner
     error: false
};

case MOVIELIST_THEATER_SUCCESS:
  return {
     ...state,
     theaterList: action.payload,
     loading: false,
     error: false
};

case MOVIELIST_THEATER_FAILURE:
  return {
     ...state,
     loading: false,
     error: true
};

...
```

Read [this](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) for more details.

============

Update:

Change your action to this:

```
export const fetchDetail = ({ enCity, cnName }) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(request_theater());

       fetch(`https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/detail?city=${enCity}&movie=${cnName}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
            dispatch({ type: MOVIE_DETAIL, payload: responseData[0].movie });
            })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));    
   };
};

export function request_theater() {
    return {
        type: MOVIE_REQUEST_THEATER
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am a little bit confused with your code. In fact i call my action to fetch data and return it to my reducer will be succeed every time. It will not used for  three actions if my action `MOVIELIST_THEATER` succeed every time.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or should i make some change in my action ? But i can't find where can i make the change.  I have update my `action.js` in my question.

Comment: @徐博俊 You're right, I'm editing my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @徐博俊 You are using only one action for your request, you need to implement the 3 that I explained. I recommend reading the link that I put at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MRFrhn it helps me have some direction to try , it's still fail when i try it, i update it in my question. Can you give me some suggestions again with my code again ?  Thank you very much.

Comment: @徐博俊 I updated my answer. hope it works, if not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, i try it. It's still no working, I `console.log('request_theater');` under `request_theater` function. `request_theater` doesn't show out, looks like problem is here i think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171426/discussion-between-mrfrhn-and-).

Comment: Fix the problem now , its my mistake, i put the code in the wrong action. It is working now, thank you very much !

Comment: How to show activity indicator while updating a call in react-redux